# Is there any way to validate two pattern in a single setValidators() in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

I have a control in angular and I want to validate both Ipaddress and Ipaddress range in a single control.
I used:

```
controls["CapPoolVolExpolAldClientControl"].setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}$/),Validators.pattern(/([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}\/[0-9]{1,2}$/)]).
```

I even try with `Validators.compose()` not working. any way out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify the pattern as:

```
                                                                      Here
                                                                     \/\/\/
Validators.pattern(/([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){2,3}$/)
```

which will validate the minimum value as 2 (which your second pattern does) and 3 is for max value and make sure you are calling [`updateValueAndValidity()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity) method after modification in the validation.

[`Stackblitz Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-setvalidators-hzs9rf)

Comment: Not working this regex. I also put updateValueAndValidity() but not works

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz demo?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the input to have no problems, it needs to fulfill all of the given validators. Currently, you have 2 validators doing this:

```
/([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}$/
/([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}\/[0-9]{1,2}$/
```

The first one is completely contained inside the second one. This means that you can either completely remove the first one and only let the second or remove the first one and make the part `\/[0-9]{1,2}` optional.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom Validator and add multiple check inside that function, something like this

**Try this**

```
function combinePattern(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
  if (control.value) {
    console.log(control.value);
    var value: string = control.value;
    const patter1 = /([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}$/;
    const pattern2 = /([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]){1,3}\/[0-9]{1,2}$/;
    if ( patter1.test(value) || pattern2.test(value)) {
      return { pattern: true };
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5wh5i)